# /etc/sudoers file is completely corrupted parse error in /etc/sudoers

Tags: raspbian, sudo

When I edited my sudoers file & saved it on my Raspberry Pi, it's giving me:

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 26 
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting 
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin on raspberry pi
```

I am trying to avoid sudo permissions for a bash which is trying to access a root file.
I also tried `pkexec`, like a general Linux solution, but it's giving

```
-bash: pkexec: command not found
```

Now this error is showing everywhere I go using sudo.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the couple of lines before and after line 26 so we can see what the issue may be.

Comment: @Hurgh, you need root permissions to read `sudoers`

Comment: Boot off a live cd and mount the partition will allow you to view/edit/fix the sudoers file.

Comment: if i can access any how to sudoers this discussion is not being taken place here. on every sudo permission giving same thing `sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 26` 
          `sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting` 
          `sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Comment: Are you asking for a way to fix it without putting the SD card in a PC? A valid sudoers is required for you to get permission to edit sudoers (barring any privilege escalation exploits) Since you put syntax errors in this file, sudo will never allow you to edit it again.

Comment: sorry my mistake above reply is for @Hurgh. John La Rooy, No i know that i also have tried to enter into root user but one more problem i didn't set password for root using su.

Comment: There is one more solution for this boot from single user mode but its not get stopped as boot time for any response is there anybody tried single user mode boot on Raspi

Answer (score 8):

It's a good idea to use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file. It will prevent you from saving the file with errors.

The easiest way to fix it will be to mount the SD card on a linux PC (or use a live cd) and fix the file there